# Why does the example from official docs of skrape{it} not compile

Tags: html, kotlin, web-scraping

There is example piece of code from official [website](https://docs.skrape.it/docs/dsl/extracting-data-from-websites) of skrape{it}. It is about extracting data from website. I'm using library version 1.0.0-alpha6

```
import it.skrape.core.htmlDocument
import it.skrape.selects.and
import it.skrape.selects.eachImage
import it.skrape.selects.eachText
import it.skrape.selects.html5.a
import it.skrape.selects.html5.div
import it.skrape.selects.html5.p
import it.skrape.selects.html5.span
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

// just some object where we will store our scraped data
data class MyExtractedData(
            var httpMessage: String = "",
            var userName: String = "",
            var repositoryNames: List<String> = emptyList(),
            var theThirdRepositoriesName: String = "",
            var firstThreeHrefs: List<String> = emptyList(),
            var overviewLink: String = "",
            var firstThreeImageSources: List<String> = emptyList(),
            var title: String = "",
            var starsCount: String = ""
    )

fun main() {
    val extracted = skrape { // 1️⃣
        url = "https://github.com/skrapeit" 
    
        extractIt<MyExtractedData> { it ->
            it.httpMessage = status { message } // 2️⃣
            htmlDocument { // 3️⃣
                relaxed = true // 4️⃣
    
                it.userName = ".h-card .p-nickname" { findFirst { text } } // 5️⃣
                val repositories = span(".repo") { findAll { this }} // 6️⃣
                println("hello world") // 7️⃣
                it.repositoryNames = repositories.filter { it.text.contains("skrape") }.eachText // 8️⃣
                it.theThirdRepositoriesName = span(".repo") { 
                    2 { text } // 9️⃣
                }
                it.firstThreeImageSources = findAll { eachImage.map { image -> image.value } }.take(3) // 1️⃣0️⃣
                it.firstThreeHrefs = findAll { eachHref }.take(3) // 1️⃣1️⃣ 
                it.overviewLink = findAll { eachLink["Overview"] ?: "not found" } // 1️⃣2️⃣ 
                it.title = titleText // 1️⃣3️⃣
    
                // *️⃣
                it.starsCount = div { // 1️⃣5️⃣ 
                    withClass = "pinned-item-list-item"
                    findFirst {
                        p { // 1️⃣6️⃣
                            findSecond {
                                a {
                                    // 1️⃣7️⃣ 
                                    withClass = "pinned-item-meta" and "muted-link" // 1️⃣8️⃣
                                    withAttribute = "href" to "/skrapeit/skrape.it/stargazers" // 1️⃣9️⃣
    
                                    findFirst {
                                        ownText
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    println(extracted)
}
```

This piece of code simply does not compile. All possible imports had been done.

Errors:

1. Unresolved reference: status
2. Unresolved reference: message
3. Unresolved reference: relaxed
4. Function invocation 'eachText()' expected (line with 8️⃣ comment)
5. Expression '2' of type 'Int' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found (line with 9️⃣ comment)
6. Type mismatch. Required: List. Found: List (line with 1️⃣0️⃣ comment)

And that's not all. There are lots of errors almost in every line. Where is the mistake?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know I has been a while, but I was looking at the scrape{it} yesterday for the first time and face the same issue as you did.
The guys have an error on the official docs (probably it is just a way it used to work before).

To make it work, you need to change the top of the function slightly:

```
val extracted = skrape(HttpFetcher) { // 1️⃣
            request {
                url = "https://github.com/skrapeit"
            }
```

It did a trick for me, hope will help someone as well.